# No me abre mi pagina web

Tags: php, web, cpanel

Ayer estaba haciendo cambios en mi pagina web agregando unas cositas y modificando otras..
pero estaba en perfecto estado.. hoy entro y me aparece que no puedo entrar como siempre y despues de tanto averiguar veo que con www no me abre mi web como puedo solucionar este problema.

http://www.institutovesalio.edu.pe/

desde este link no me abre mi pagina web.. y me gustaria saber porq?

http://institutovesalio.edu.pe/

en cambio de este si abre como puedo solucionar este problema gracias.

Comment: Te falta el registro **A** en tu DNS que apunte el subdominio `www` a tu IP `161.132.18.183`, o bien un registro **CNAME** que apunte el subdominio `www` a `institutovesalio.edu.pe` (o bien a `@`).  Mira si tocastes algo de eso recientemente y vuélvelo a poner como estaba.  Una vez hecho ese cambio puede tardar, como mucho, unas 48 horas en ser efectivo a nivel mundial (a nivel local en unas pocas horas seria suficiente). Tus servidores de nombres son NS2.RCP.NET.pe y NS.RCP.NET.pe... supongo que tienes algun panel de control en tu registrador de dominio para modificar todo eso.

Comment: Tienes que configurar el subdominio www busca en Internet como hacerlo porque eso en que no lo tienes configurado